# Cannot insert data to foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

`ClassTable`:**

```
CREATE TABLE ClassTable 
(
    className varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
    classFee  int,
    academicYear int
);
```

`StudentTable`:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentTable  
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastName varchar(255),
    fatherName varchar(255),
    fatherNo varchar(255),
    motherName varchar(255),
    motherNo varchar(255),
    dob date,
    dor date,
    gender varchar(255),
    className varchar(255),
    healthInsuranceNo varchar(255),
    resAddress varchar(255),
    photo Image,

    CONSTRAINT FK_StudentTable 
        FOREIGN KEY (className) REFERENCES ClassTable(className)
);
```

C# code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StudentTable (firstName, lastName, fatherName, fatherNo, motherName, motherNo, dob, dor, gender, className, healthInsuranceNo, resAddress, photo) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @fatherName, @fatherNo, @motherName, @motherNo, @dob, @dor, @gender, @className, @healthInsuranceNo, @resAddress, @photo)", con);
con.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txt_FirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txt_LastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fatherName", txt_FatherName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fatherNo", txt_FatherNo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motherName", txt_MotherName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motherNo", txt_MotherNo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateTimePickerDOB.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dor", dateTimePickerDOR.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", cmb_Gender.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@className", cmb_Class.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@healthInsuranceNo", txt_HealthInsurance.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resAddress", txt_Address.Text);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img_Box.Image.Save(ms, img_Box.Image.RawFormat);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", ms.ToArray());

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Accountant successfully registered.");
```

When I manually write the query to SQL Server it allows me to insert data to the foreign key column (`className`) but when I try to insert from my C# Winforms application, I get this error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_StudentTable". The conflict occurred in database "SchoolDatabase",  table "dbo.ClassTable", column 'className'.

I used this query to manually enter a record in the database and it worked:

```
INSERT INTO StudentTable (firstName, className) 
VALUES ('name here', 'class one');
```

Comment: What are the values you're trying to insert?  The error is pretty clear, it's trying to insert a value which doesn't exist in the `ClassTable` table.

Comment: Side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Please do not shout. Using upper case tends to discourage people from helping you. Kindly test the value of cmb_Class.Text. I suspect this is a ComboBox? Do you need SelectedText instead?

Comment: The values already exist in class table and those values are being populated in drop down on the form and the selected value from drop-down. i am trying to insert in student table having FK column(className). I know what you are saying i have basic understanding like the primary key column should have the data before inserting data to foreign key column also the value being inserted in foreign key should be the same one existed in primary key column.

Comment: I have class table with column className(PK) and student table with columns firstname and className(FK). when the form loads class names from the class table populated and displaying in drop down. and i want the drop down selected value to be inserted in the student table column className(FK) although the value is same already existed in className column in class table still i see exception.

Comment: Chekc the actual value for spaces, newlines or similar characters.

Comment: I have tried everything. Nothing works.

Comment: What do you get if you add `MessageBox.Show("##" + cmb_Class.Text + "##");`?

Comment: Error Resolved! . I do not know how but there was no combo box on the form with name cmb_Class, even there was no warning when i used wrong name. The name of combo box i had to select the value from  was not written in code. Thanks Anyways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically a typo